# How can I get ALL locale independent NSTimeZone abbreviations?

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter, nstimezone, nslocale

I'm trying to get ALL existing timezone's abbreviations. `[NSTimeZone abbreviationDictionary]` only returns some of them, but some like AEST (from Australia/Brisbane) do no appear.

I found out that with this code

```
NSDate *myDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
[f setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
[f setDateFormat:@"zzzz"];

NSArray *timeZoneNames = [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames];
for (NSString *name1 in timeZoneNames)
{
    NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:name1];
    [f setTimeZone:tz];

    DLog(@"%@ = \"%@\" = %@", [tz abbreviation], name1, [f stringFromDate:myDate]);
}
```

I can get all available timezone abbreviated and full names such as:

```
EET = "Europe/Kiev" = Eastern European Standard Time
WET = "Europe/Lisbon" = Western European Standard Time
CET = "Europe/Ljubljana" = Central European Standard Time
GMT = "Europe/London" = Greenwich Mean Time
```

But the timezone names are locale-dependent (my current [[NSLocale currentLocale]localeIdentifier] is en_GB), so I get some results like:

```
GMT-4 = "America/New_York" = Eastern Daylight Time
GMT-4 = "America/Nipigon" = Eastern Daylight Time
GMT-8 = "America/Nome" = Alaska Daylight Time
GMT-2 = "America/Noronha" = Fernando de Noronha Standard Time
```

Is there a way I can get all the existing timezone abbreviations instead of GMT-X?

Any help is much appreciated :)

Thank you!

Comment: you do know they arent standarized .. so this is potientionally only valid for ios?

Comment: Note that the 3 letter abbreviations are not unique or standardised and Europe/London in the summer is BST not only the GMY you give there

Comment: yes, this will be an iOS only app. I need the timezone's abbreviated name so I can send it to my servers and then do some date-related math

@Mark I will manage the "daylight saving time" offset afterwards, but first I need to get all the possible abbreviations

Comment: see below for a way to get GMT-

Comment: What do you do if you set BST as an answer ? British Summer Time, Brazil Standard Time or Bering Summer Time? - Stick with the GMT/UTC offsets internally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get those abbreviations, because they're not standard. Apple, like most computer makers, uses the semi-official [IANA time zone database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones). IANA does not consider "AEST" to be a standard abbreviation (in fact their `australasia` file includes significant discussion on this exact question), so it's not included in iOS's time zone data.

Comment: Thank all of you for your help. I've finally decided to use the "continent/city" code (some but not all of them are shown here [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]) to identify my user's timezone. It's much more compatible and standarized.

Answer (score 1):

use the names to get all zones and to get the secondsFromGMT:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        for(NSString *name in [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]) {
            NSTimeZone *z = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:name];
            NSLog(@"%@", z.name); //name

            NSLog(@"GMT-%d", (z.secondsFromGMT/60)/60); //GMT-%D%

            NSLog(@"%@", z.abbreviation); //abbreviation
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This method outputs timezones like this:
    "Europe/Paris
    GMT-1"

I would need something like:
    "Europe/Paris
    CET"

(CET == Central European Standard Time)

Comment: FWIK the abbreviation is not locale-independent (e.g. may be MESZ instead of CEST).